# Buttons aligned in a row

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i align these buttons dynamically that it doesnot go overflow and be responsive[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upp6s.png)

Comment: Post with your code that what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Wrap widget, like this

```
Wrap(
  direction: Axis.horizontal,
  alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 10),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text(' Button 1 '),
      )),
    Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 10),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text(' Button 2 '),
      )),
    Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 10),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text(' Button 3 '),
      )),
    Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 10),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text(' Button 4 '),
      )),
    Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 10),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text(' Button 5 '),
      )),
    Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 10),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text(' Button 7 '),
      )),
    Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 10),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text(' Button 7 '),
      ))
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridView.Builder for archive this type of layout. Change Spacing and childAspectRatio as per your need. and try below code.

```
GridView.builder(
                              gridDelegate:
                                  const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                crossAxisCount: 3,
                                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                                mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                                childAspectRatio: 0.7,
                              ),
                              itemCount: yourList.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
return YourButton()}
```